# No SSH access after reboot

Tags: ssh, fedora, login, remote-access

I am having an issue where I can access a server remotely via SSH but if I send the reboot command. Once the server reboots I get a timeout when I try to relogin. The only way to fix the problem is to issue the following commands *"service iptables restart"* and *"service sshd restart"* from the physical server commandline. I use a non-standard port to access the server via SSH. The firewall is set to allow access on that port.

Can someone tell why this is happening?

Comment: Are you redirecting your "non-standard port" to port 22 using iptables, or is ssh listening directly on the "non-standard port"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have another firewall installed with its own initscript, and restarting the `iptables` service wipes the rules it adds and puts its own in place. The output of `iptables -L` after rebooting as well as a listing of the contents of `/etc/init.d` can confirm this.

Comment: You are correct! I recently made many changes to my network (hardware related) and I had forgot that I had Advanced Policy Firewall (apf) installed on the system. A quick change of port numbers in the *conf.apf* for *IG_TCP_CPORTS* and *IG_UDP_CPORTS* and all worked again when rebooting from a remote system.

Answer (score 1):

When you do either of the "service servicename restart", does one (or both) produce output like the following:

```
Stopping sshd:                                             [FAILED]
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
```

If either sshd, or iptables produce the "failed" then "ok" when you issue a restart, it isn't getting started from init.  You can fix that with

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig sshd on
```

or

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig iptables on
```